# Disable event confirmation by default

Tags: civievent

Is there a way to set 'Event confirmation' to 'no' by default? It can done for each event but can this be turned off once and for all?

Comment: Do you mean event confirmation screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean to turn off Confirmation screen for Events by default when an Event is created then you can either

1. Implement [pre hook](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_pre/)  to set is_confirm_enabled = 0 when $op is create and Objectname is Event

or

2. Run below sql query

   ALTER TABLE `civicrm_event` CHANGE `is_confirm_enabled` `is_confirm_enabled` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'If false, the event booking confirmation screen gets skipped';

**Note:** For paid events Civi by default doesn't skip Confirmation page.

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: more than a great answer, thanks Pradeep! I've run a `UPDATE `civicrm_event` SET `is_confirm_enabled`='0' WHERE `is_confirm_enabled` LIKE '1' to modify the events already created

Comment: For those using WordPress, Christian Wach pushed an update of CiviCRM Event Organiser that offers this option from backend: https://github.com/christianwach/civicrm-event-organiser

Comment: Noting if you chose option 2 then the schema default gets reset back to 1 if you upgrade to 5.49.